# STM32L496ZG, 7 segments display task, SysTick interrut not called?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt-handling, segment

I made  progress with the last task of blinking all leds over and over again.
Now I'm trying to show actual time (two modes, one showing time in HHMM and the second MMSS) on my 7 segments displayer.
Segments from A to G are responsible arefor digit "parts", DP is dot.
Connection between segments and pins is represented on board as follows:

```
A → GPIO_G[0]
B → GPIO_G[1]
C → GPIO_G[2]
D → GPIO_G[3]
E → GPIO_G[4]
F → GPIO_G[5]
G → GPIO_G[6]
DP → GPIO_G[9]
```

Base transistors NPN responsible for seeing of the digit:

```
DIG_1 → GPIO_B[2] 
DIG_2 → GPIO_B[3]
DIG_3 → GPIO_B[4]
DIG_4 → GPIO_B[5]
```

I'm using JOY_UP and JOY_DOWN for change of mode:

```
JOY_UP → GPIO_E[2]
JOY_DOWN → GPIO_E[3]
```

Here is my code:
main.c

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2021 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void switchInit(void);
void baseTransistInit(void);
void segmentsInit();
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  HAL_PWREx_EnableVddIO2();
  switchInit();
  baseTransistInit();
  segmentsInit();
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */
  SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000); // SysTick_Handler() called within 1ms
  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void switchInit(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef Joys;
    Joys.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
    Joys.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2 /* JOY_UP */ | GPIO_PIN_3 /* JOY_DOWN */;
    Joys.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    Joys.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    Joys.Alternate = 0;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &Joys);
}

void baseTransistInit(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef Transistors;
    Transistors.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    Transistors.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5;
    Transistors.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    Transistors.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    Transistors.Alternate = 0;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &Transistors);
}

void segmentsInit()
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef Segments;
    Segments.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    Segments.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6 | GPIO_PIN_9;
    Segments.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    Segments.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    Segments.Alternate = 0;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &Segments);
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

stm32l4xx_it.c:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    stm32l4xx_it.c
  * @brief   Interrupt Service Routines.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2021 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_it.h"
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN TD */

/* USER CODE END TD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define SEG_A 0
#define SEG_B 1
#define SEG_C 2
#define SEG_D 3
#define SEG_E 4
#define SEG_F 5
#define SEG_G 6
#define SEG_DP 9
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
int hourFirst = 1, hourSecond = 5;
int minuteFirst = 3, minuteSecond = 0;
int secondFirst = 0, secondSecond = 0;
int showHHMM = 0, showMMSS = 0;
int buttonMs = 0;
int buttonDelay = 500;
int miliSeconds = 0;
const uint16_t  tableOfSegments[] =  {
        1 << SEG_A | 1 << SEG_B | 1 << SEG_C | 1 << SEG_D | 1 << SEG_E | 1 << SEG_F,              // DIGIT 0
        1 << SEG_B | 1 << SEG_C,                                                                  // DIGIT 1
        1 << SEG_A | 1 << SEG_B | 1 << SEG_E | 1 << SEG_D | 1 << SEG_G,                           // DIGIT 2
        1 << SEG_A | 1 << SEG_B | 1 << SEG_C | 1 << SEG_D | 1 << SEG_E,                           // DIGIT 3
        1 << SEG_B | 1 << SEG_C | 1 << SEG_G | 1 << SEG_F,                                        // DIGIT 4
        1 << SEG_A | 1 << SEG_F | 1 << SEG_G | 1 << SEG_C | 1 << SEG_D,                           // DIGIT 5
        1 << SEG_A | 1 << SEG_F | 1 << SEG_G | 1 << SEG_C | 1 << SEG_D | 1 << SEG_E,              // DIGIT 6
        1 << SEG_A | 1 << SEG_B | 1 << SEG_C,                                                     // DIGIT 7
        1 << SEG_A | 1 << SEG_B | 1 << SEG_C | 1 << SEG_D | 1 << SEG_E | 1 << SEG_F | 1 << SEG_G, // DIGIT 8
        1 << SEG_A | 1 << SEG_B | 1 << SEG_C | 1 << SEG_D | 1 << SEG_F | 1 << SEG_G,              // DIGIT 9

};
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void changeSeconds();
void changeMinutes();
void changeHours();

void inputHandling();
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
void changeSeconds()
{
    if(secondSecond < 9)
        secondSecond++;
    else if(secondSecond == 9)
    {
        if(secondFirst < 5)
        {
            secondSecond = 0;
            secondFirst++;
        }
        else // secondSecond == 9 && secondFirst == 5
        {
            secondSecond = 0;
            secondFirst = 0;
            changeMinutes();
        }
    }
}

void changeMinutes()
{
    if(minuteSecond < 9)
        minuteSecond++;
    else if(minuteSecond == 9)
    {
        if(minuteFirst < 5)
        {
            minuteSecond = 0;
            minuteSecond++;
        }
        else // minutesSecond == 9 && minutesFirst == 5
        {
            minuteSecond = 0;
            minuteFirst = 0;
            changeHours();
        }
    }
}

void changeHours()
{
    if(hourFirst <= 1 && hourSecond < 9)
        hourSecond++;
    else if(hourFirst <= 1 && hourSecond == 9)
    {
        hourSecond = 0;
        hourFirst++;
    }
    else if(hourFirst == 2 && hourSecond < 3)
        hourSecond++;
    else
    {
        hourSecond = 0;
        hourFirst = 0;
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/* External variables --------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN EV */

/* USER CODE END EV */

/******************************************************************************/
/*           Cortex-M4 Processor Interruption and Exception Handlers          */
/******************************************************************************/
/**
  * @brief This function handles Non maskable interrupt.
  */
void NMI_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN NonMaskableInt_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END NonMaskableInt_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN NonMaskableInt_IRQn 1 */
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END NonMaskableInt_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Hard fault interrupt.
  */
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Memory management fault.
  */
void MemManage_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Prefetch fault, memory access fault.
  */
void BusFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN BusFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END BusFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_BusFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_BusFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Undefined instruction or illegal state.
  */
void UsageFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN UsageFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles System service call via SWI instruction.
  */
void SVC_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVCall_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SVCall_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVCall_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SVCall_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Debug monitor.
  */
void DebugMon_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DebugMonitor_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DebugMonitor_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DebugMonitor_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DebugMonitor_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles Pendable request for system service.
  */
void PendSV_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles System tick timer.
  */
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_IncTick();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 1 */
  miliSeconds++;
  inputHandling();
  if((miliSeconds % 1000) == 0 || miliSeconds == 1)
  {
       HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5 | GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
       HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3 | GPIO_PIN_4 | GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
       if(showHHMM)
       {
           if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 0)
           {
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, tableOfSegments[hourFirst], GPIO_PIN_SET);
           }
           else if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 1)
           {
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, tableOfSegments[hourSecond], GPIO_PIN_SET);
           }
           else if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 2)
           {
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, tableOfSegments[minuteFirst], GPIO_PIN_SET);
           }
           else if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 3)
           {
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, tableOfSegments[minuteSecond], GPIO_PIN_SET);

               return;
           }
           else if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 4)
           {
               miliSeconds = 0;
           }
           changeSeconds();
       }
       else if(showMMSS)
       {
           if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 0)
           {
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, tableOfSegments[minuteFirst], GPIO_PIN_SET);
           }
           else if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 1)
           {
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, tableOfSegments[minuteSecond], GPIO_PIN_SET);
           }
           else if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 2)
           {
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, tableOfSegments[secondFirst], GPIO_PIN_SET);
           }
           else if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 3)
           {
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, tableOfSegments[secondSecond], GPIO_PIN_SET);
               return;
           }
           else if(miliSeconds / 1000 == 4)
           {
               miliSeconds = 0;
           }
           changeSeconds();

       }
  }
  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 1 */
}

/******************************************************************************/
/* STM32L4xx Peripheral Interrupt Handlers                                    */
/* Add here the Interrupt Handlers for the used peripherals.                  */
/* For the available peripheral interrupt handler names,                      */
/* please refer to the startup file (startup_stm32l4xx.s).                    */
/******************************************************************************/

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
void inputHandling()
{
    buttonMs++;
    if(buttonMs < buttonDelay)
        return;
    if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_2 ) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    {
        buttonMs = 0;
        showMMSS = 1;
        showHHMM = 0;
        return;
    }
    else if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_3) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    {
        buttonMs = 0;
        showMMSS = 0;
        showHHMM = 1;
        return;
    }

}
/* USER CODE END 1 */
```

My code in SysTick_Handler is just for the start (in the beginning I want to see if digits are correctly seen one by one within 1 second of change from digit to digit).
But... it doesn't work. My board is showing no change in my displayer after running my code. I can only guess that SysTick_Handler() isn't called at all, but I can't be sure.

Maybe you know what the problem is? Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: It is called for sure. Your code does not.

Comment: @0___________ Could you tell me more where the problem is? Is it with my construct of SysTick_Handler funtion? If that so mu guess is it's never going into if block of code.

Comment: @0___________ Oh, now i see it. Both variables "showHHMM" and "showMMSS" were intialised with values 0. And that's why no changes were made to segments and transistors.